# Change the arrow on association in UML-designer Eclipse plugin

Tags: uml-designer

I'm using the latest `uml-designer` with Eclipse NEON.2.
Any time I create association between classes it adds the direction arrow. I can change the diamonds from the properties window. However, the only way I found to change the arrow is by going into the `Properties->Style->TargetArrow` field. It works, but seems a bit hacky. Is there a more direct way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are just changing the **style** of the select association, you do not modify the **semantic** element. It fou want to set that an association is *non navigable* then you need to select the association and go to the the `Properties` View -> `General` tab ->  `Member End` property and uncheck the Navigable checkbox in the table.

[image: Association Navigability]